# How to configure Android in Myeclipse 2014 IDE

Tags: android, adt, facebook-android-sdk, myeclipse

How to configure Android in Myeclipse 2014 IDE.
I mean how to develop android apps from myeclipse 2014.
As recommended I've chosen "Help" on IDE's menu then "install from site" option then added this url "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"
but at last it gives "installing software has encountered problem".
What to do,should I use Eclipse Ide downloaded as part of "adt-bundle-windows-x86".
But i want to use Myeclipse 2014 IDE.
Is Myeclipse 2014 a superior IDE from Eclipse Luna/Juno or it facilitates as in same way in context of developing android apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the ADT package directly from https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.3.zip and installing it in MyEclipse by adding the downloaded zip file as a repository in the "Install new Software" screen where you previously put the URL.

Check here for more detailed instructions and an up to date download link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

And here for a description of some common issues:
http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/troubleshooting.html#installeclipsecomponents

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

MyEclipse 2014 has some early access tools for building mobile apps for IOS and Android. You can see the overview here: http://docs.myeclipseide.com/topic/com.genuitec.eclipse.mobile.doc/html/overview/enterprise_mobile/index.html?cp=1_6_0 and follow tutorials there.

MyEclipse 2015 CI has updated (and changed) PhoneGap tools, so that might be a better version to try out. It can be downloaded from here: http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-4.html